# Finding whether or not an object exists within a Parse Relation Query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to utilize Parse as a back-end for my applications, I have set up a "relation" between 2 objects (ParseUser and SingleWorkout). Within this ParseUser Object, I keep a relation named "user_likes" and "user_favorites" and this relation holds the SingleWorkout Object relation.

I would like to just be able to see if the relation exists between the ParseUser Object and the SingleWorkout Object, and if it does return a true/false.

Here are 2 methods I wrote to perform the query, I am expecting to receive in the callback a 0 if there is not relation, and a 1 if there is a relation as there can only be 1 relation on a specific objectId.

**The issue is that this query is returning a -1, and 0 and sometimes it will just return a 0. How can I adjust my query to return whether or not a relation exists between the 2 objects?**

```
private void queryLikeRelation() {
    relation = currentUser.getRelation("user_likes");
    query = relation.getQuery();
    query.whereExists(currentSingleWorkout.getObjectId());
    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(int i, ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, i + "LIKE OBJECTS");
            if (i == -1){
                isStillLiked = true;
                ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_content_selector);
                isLikeChecked = true;
            } else {
                isStillLiked = false;
                ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_blank_content_selector);
                isLikeChecked = false;
            }
        }
    });

}

private void queryFavoriteRelation() {
    relation = currentUser.getRelation("user_favorites");
    query = relation.getQuery();
    query.whereExists(currentSingleWorkout.getObjectId());
    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(int i, ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, i + "FAVORITE OBJECTS");
            if (i == -1){
                isStillFavorited = true;
                ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_content_selector);
                isFavoriteChecked = true;
            } else {
                isStillFavorited = false;
                ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_blank_content_selector);
                isFavoriteChecked = false;
            }
        }
    });
```